# Is there a way to set up characters with 5 digits of unicode as dead key code points in MSKLC?

Tags: unicode

[image: picture]

Is there any way to overcome this software limitation?
As seen here

[image: as seen here]

it only takes inputs of 4 digits long while i need to input in unicode keys 5 digits long, when I try to do it, an error message saying "The value must be either a single character or a code point" pops up

Comment: According to the help files for MSKLC 1.4, which is the currently-available download, the codepoints are all UTF-16, so it's likely that what you seek to do is not possible with this program.

Comment: You might want to look at [KbdEdit](https://kbdedit.com) as an alternative to MSKLC. It's not free, though.

Comment: Reading the documentation for KbdEdit, I think you're out of luck: *Due to an internal Windows limitation, dead characters are restricted to operating only against **single BMP** (<=FFFF) Unicode characters. This restriction applies to all components of a dead character transformation: the "from" and "to" characters, as well as the dead character itself.*

Comment: damn, thanks btw @JeffZeitlin

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for MSKLC 1.4 (the currently available version) indicates that the codepoints used must all be UTF-16. One alternative to MSKLC that I looked into, [KbdEdit](https://kbdedit.com/), went into a little more detail in their documentation:

> *Due to an internal Windows limitation, dead characters are restricted to operating only against **single BMP** (<=FFFF) Unicode characters. This restriction applies to all components of a dead character transformation; the “from” and “to” characters, as well as the dead character itself.*

So, the short answer to the question is “It can’t be done.”

There are unicode code points with names that include the word ‘combining’; often, you can get the visual effect you want/need by using these - for example, if for some reason you wanted a macron over the DESERET CAPITAL LETTER SHORT OO (0x1040B), you would insert that letter followed by COMBINING MACRON (0x303).

Comment: what I'm trying to do currently is to implement the old Turkic runic alphabet but i've ran out of keys in the keyboard for it. I tried to use AltGr/Ctrl + key combinations but they dont seem to write anything, probably due to the fact that Windows reserves those stuff, but the weird thing is that in stock layouts, i can normally use altgr combinations like AltGr + 4 for a dollar sign, my last resort would be to change the keys that use the shift combination that are same no matter its "case" with the remaining ones, but do you see a way out of this problem without using that last resort?

Comment: If your problem is that you're trying to use code points outside of the BMP, you simply can't do it with the MSKLC, or with anything that uses the same internal mechanism. However, I'm pretty sure you CAN do almost anything you want if you're willing to get into [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) programming.